# Doubling dx and dy

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, chain-rule, infinitesimals

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$. Thus the total differential is $df=f_x dx + f_y dy$. Does doubling $dx$ and $dy$ double $df$. I want to multiply everything by $2$ but since we are dealing with infinitesimals I am hesitant to do so.

Comment: Note that using $dx,dy,df$ is notation and not infinitesimal(most of the times). But let me ask you: $$\int dx=\int 2dx?$$(up to constant, or even for *some* constant)

Comment: @Holo They are not equal.

Comment: exactly, even though I just multiply the $dx$ by $2$

Comment: @Holo I am not quite sure I get what you are trying to say ?

Comment: if in my example $dx$ was multiply by $2$ why would it be different here?

Answer (score 2):

Think of the total differential as a linear operator: The action of $df(p)$ on a vector of changes $(dx,dy)$ is given by $f_x(p)dx+f_y(p)dy$ where I added a point $p$ to stress that the partial derivatives, hence the differential, depend on some point $p$ where they are evaluated. By linearity, doubling the vector of changes $(dx,dy)$ and then applying the differential will double the result:
$$df(p)(2dx,2dy)=f_x(p)(2dx)+f_y(p)(2dy)=2(f_x(p)dx+f_y(p)dy)$$

Comment: Hmm .. So doubling both rates indeed doubles df.

Answer (score 1):

One way to use the total differential is to create a Taylor series around a point, so $f(x,y)\approx f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$  You can certainly double $x-x_0$ and $y-y_0$ to get the value of $f$ at a different point.  Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: I want to know if doubling the rates of change dx and dy doubles df. I am not sure I get your idea.

Comment: $dx$ and $dy$ are amounts of change, not rates.  That is reflected in the use of $x-x_0$.  If you double the change you double the change in function value from the starting point.